# Github.pages tutorial, links crossed

Tags: python, github, jekyll

Currently my site YourDataTalking.com is pointing to the tutorial from which it was made but I need it to point to the repo I forked and edited in Github. The repo I pulled the data from is https://github.com/jarrekk/Jalpc Which is a Jekyll tutorial that I found as node.js is in my stack of "things to dabble"

[datatalking/yourdatatalking.github.io](http://datatalking/yourdatatalking.github.io)

So yeah... I have my wires crossed somewhere and I'm about 4 in to searching through all the files for the second time and don't know where the link is bad.

The tutorial seems to make this simple but I don't know where I have the links crossed.

```
# Welcome to Jekyll!

# Website settings
title: Jalpc
description: Jack's blog,use Jekyll and github pages.
keywords: Jack,Jalpc,blog,Jekyll,github,gh-pages
baseurl:  /Jalpc # if you have suburl as homepage like '/homepage', please change it to '/homepage' and your repo's name should be 'homepage'
url: http://jarrekk.github.io/Jalpc  # url should be changed to 'http://www.jack003.com/homepage' as before
# url: http://127.0.0.1:4000
img_path: /Jalpc/static/assets/img/blog  # url should be changed to '/homepage/static/assets/img/blog' as before

# author -- index page "about me" section
author:  # change following line to your infomation.
  name: GitHub  # Be used at blog posts' author.
  first_name: Hub  # Be used at index page about me section.
  last_name: Git  # Be used at index page about me section.
  cv: http://cv.jack003.com  # A online CV can be printed as PDF, leave blank if you don't have now
  email: me@jack003.com  # Leave blank if you don't have now
  facebook_username: jiakunnj  # Leave blank if you don't have now
  github_username: jarrekk  # Leave blank if you don't have now
  avatar: /static/assets/img/landing/avatar.jpg  # upload your avatar at directory and edit it.
  skill_icon1:
    - name: icon-apache
    - name: fa-linux
  skill_icon2:
    - name: fa-linux
    - name: icon-apache
  desc: Introduce myself will be here.

# comment
disqus:  # if you wanna comment feature, go to https://disqus.com/ to get your configuration; if not, comment following two lines.
  name: jalpc
  public_key: tj2MPaNlHMONwTH5bGDNSXyaBpW7q282MeUzh5CwcjJerNhK8Kxk3aWo7IckzTX7

# analytics
## google analytics
ga:  # if you wanna this feature, go to https://www.google.com/analytics/ to get your configuration; if not, comment following line.
  # id:

## growingIO
gio:  # if you wanna this feature, go to https://www.growingio.com/ to get your configuration; if not, comment following line.
  # id:

## donation
donation: on  # type 'on'/'off' to choice display donation button at post page or not


# Build settings
encoding: utf-8

# other settings
highlighter: rouge
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
  input: GFM
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
```

Comment: datatalking/yourdatatalking.github.io is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this line:
`url: http://jarrekk.github.io/Jalpc`

is the page that would be opened - have you tried changing it to the page that you want it to open, your own URL

`url: http://datatalking/yourdatatalking.github.io`

Or whatever your correct URL is.

It might be something like this:
`url: http://yourdatatalking.github.io/` once you have your page propertly set up on github?

**A little further research**

And, according to the GitHub pages documentation at [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) - your new repository has to have the exact username of your account on GitHub, so it should be `datatalking.github.io`, if your GitHub account name is `datatalking`.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to search a github folder for a url string?

Comment: There is a search box at the top of the GitHub web page?  Maybe that will work?

Comment: It kinda works, I was also looking for a way to search my .py files in sandbox for that URL string and I'll add this to my list when I have time next week.